# 422: Unprocessable Entity with FastAPI and MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi

I'm trying to achieve a very simple update of data in MongoDB database and I cannot understand why it is not working.

Here's my code:

`models.py`:

```
class Text(BaseModel):
    id: str = Field(default_factory=uuid.uuid4, alias="_id")
    text: str = Field(...)
    gold: bool = Field(...)
    annotations: int = Field(...)

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        schema_extra = {
            'example': {
                '_id': '066de609-b04a-4b30-b46c-32537c7f1f6e',
                'text': 'The first mission to the moon happend in 1969...',
                'gold': 'False',
                'annotations': '1'
            }
        }

class AnnotationCountUpdate(BaseModel):
    annotations: int = Field(...)

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "annotations": 1
            }
        }
```

`routes.py`:

```
@router.put("/{text_id}", response_description="Update text annotation count", response_model=Text)
def update_count(text_id: str, request: Request, update: AnnotationCountUpdate = Body(...)):
    update = {k: v for k, v in update.dict().items() if v is not None}
    if len(update) >= 1:
        update_result =  request.app.data.update_one(
            {"_id": text_id}, {"set": update}
        )
        if update_result.modified_count == 0:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f"Text with ID {text_id} not found")

    if (existing_text := request.app.data.find_one({"_id": text_id})) is not None:
        return existing_text

    raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f"Text with ID {text_id} not found")
```

Here's how my database looks:

[image]

Here's the full response I get:

[image]

I can't figure it out for the life of me...

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any other routes defined? i.e. are you sure that's the actual route that you're matching? Seeing as it mentions fields not defined in the body, I'm guessing you're matching a different endpoint than what you think.

Comment: Unbelievable! That was the issue indeed. I've got another endpoint similar to this one, so I was matching it. Thank you for the help